# Flattening out nested callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

I have frustrating problem with learning to work with callback style of programming in Node.js. I have a query to a MongoDB database. If I pass in a function to execute on the result it works but I'd rather flatten it out and have it return the value. Any help or direction on how to do this correctly is appreciated. Here's my code:

```
var getLots = function(response){
    db.open(function(err, db){
        db.collection('lots', function(err, collection){
            collection.find(function(err, cursor){
                cursor.toArray(function(err, items){
                    response(items);
                })
            })
        })
    })
}
```

I want something more like this:

```
lots = function(){
    console.log("Getting lots")
    return db.open(openCollection(err, db));
}

openCollection = function(err, db){
    console.log("Connected to lots");
    return (db.collection('lots',findLots(err, collection))
    );
}

findLots = function(err, collection){
    console.log("querying 2");
    return collection.find(getLots(err, cursor));
}

getLots = function(err, cursor) {
    console.log("Getting lots");
    return cursor.toArray();
}
```

Where the final set of data would bubble back up through the function calls.

The problem is that I get an error from Node.js saying that err is not defined or that the collection is not defined. For some reason when I nest the callbacks the correct object is getting passed down. When I try going to this flattened style it complains that things are not defined. I don't know how to get it to pass the necessary objects.

Comment: What's specifically wrong with the example solution you've given?

Comment: Looks like a great idea and a good implementation.  What's the problem?

Comment: You can also try this: https://github.com/caolan/async Created for this kind of problems.

Comment: Or this: https://github.com/lm1/node-fibers-promise

Comment: The problem is that I get an error from Node.js saying that err is not defined or that the collection is not defined. For some reason when I nest the callbacks the correct object is getting passed down. When I try going to this flattened style it complains that things are not defined. I don't know how to get it to pass the necessary objects. I've added this comment to this question. Sorry for being ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is one of the many [control flow libraries](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-async-flow) available for node via npm and catalogued on the Node.js wiki. My specific recommendation is [caolan/async](https://github.com/caolan/async), and you would use the `async.waterfall` function to accomplish this type of flow where each async operation must be executed in order and each requires the results from the previous operation.

Pseudocode example:

```
function getLots(db, callback) {
   db.collection("lots", callback);
}

function findLots(collection, callback) {
    collection.find(callback);
}

function toArray(cursor, callback) {
    cursor.toArray(callback);
}

async.waterfall([db.open, getLots, find, toArray], function (err, items) {
    //items is the array of results
    //Do whatever you need here
    response(items);
});
```

Comment: Actually `async.series` does not pass arguments to next calls. He needs `async.waterfall`.

Comment: When I use this does the resulting dataset get passed back up the chain and returned to calling function? I am wanting the result of the cursor.toArray() function to be returned from this series of callbacks.

Comment: Check out the async docs. With waterfall, the callback value of each function is passed as a parameter to the next function in the chain, with the callback value of the final function being a parameter to the "done" callback function. You can chain results as needed. I'll update my answer to include an example.

Answer (score 0):

async is a good flow control library. [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) offers some specific advantages like better debugging, and better arrangement for synchronous function execution. (though it is not currently in npm like async is)

Here is what it would look like in Frame:

```
Frame(function(next){
    db.open(next);
});
Frame(function(next, err, db){
    db.collection('lots', next);
});
Frame(function(next, err, collection){
    collection.find(next);
});
Frame(function(next, err, cursor){
    cursor.toArray(next);
});
Frame(function(next, err, items){
    response(items);
    next();
});
Frame.init();
```